# Is there another use of ng-src attribute besides in <img>

Tags: angularjs

I have a Newbie AngularJS question. I was checking the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and in the [step 6](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06) there's the following line of code:

```
<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>
```

Where they explain that you must to use `ng-src` instead of `src` or else the browser will treat `{{phone.imageUrl}}` literally. However in the same line appears `href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}"` where no special tag is being used.
Why this is like that? This only applies for an `<img>` tag or there are another situations where you must to use `ng-scr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ng-src` and `src` works just fine. The only thing to notice is when the `img` tag is evaluated, angular might not be loaded so the image url won't make sense to the browser. If you can guarantee that angular will be loaded before the browser evaluates `img`, you can use `src` with angular expression as the source.

Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating this.

http://jsfiddle.net/PkpL3/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <img src="{{name}}"/>
    <img ng-src="{{name}}"/>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo5w.png';
}
```